# Regex replace throws a ReferenceError for the search param on IE11/Edge

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm sometimes getting the error `ReferenceError: '__INDEX__' is undefined` on IE11 and Edge where __INDEX__ is the search component of a regex based string replace call. Here is some example code for the replacing:

```
var subject = "1__INDEX__2__INDEX__3";
var separator = ",";
var b = subject.replace(/__INDEX__/g, separator);
```

I've been unable to replicate this, even on IE11/Edge machines, but it is happening to my end users. Is this something to do with me using a literal regex definition rather than creating an instance of the regexp object?

Edit: Actual code example to look for other sources of the issue:

```
var contactIndex = 0;
$('.js-other-contact-list').append(
    $('.js-other-contact-template')
        .html()
        .replace(/__INDEX__/g, contactIndex)
);
```

Comment: `where __INDEX__ is the search component` are you saying `__INDEX__` in the code you posted isn't necessarily the string `__INDEX__`? because your code ***as posted*** works 100% of the time

Comment: `__INDEX__` is in the subject string and is being replaced by something else, the error I get from IE/Edge is that `__INDEX__` is not defined, despite it never being referenced. It works 100% of the time for me too, but maybe 1/200 times my end users get an error in IE/Edge.

Comment: @NbodyNbody is the subject string what we see here, or is it created somewhere else ? if so where/how and how is it inserted in the `subject` variable ?

Comment: the code you posted is not the problem

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli The actual code isn't quite like this, although I kept the work being done the same. The actual code has no variables and thus nothing that it could be having a reference error on, it's all the result of jquery methods. I have added a raw snippet of the actual code now

Comment: I can only see the code failing if the `.js-other-contact-template` does not exist, but with a different error (*since `.html()` will return undefined*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli My thoughts exactly, I'm puzzled as to how \__INDEX__ could ever be undefined when it's only ever there as a regex literal

Comment: Are you using any bundler that could be messing with the original code ? Also are you using template literals anywhere else that perhaps need to be reviewed ?

Comment: No bundler, just raw javascript in a script tag. Also not using this particular literal anywhere else

Comment: Just a thought: maybe `_INDEX_` is matching some internal string / reserved keyword, possibly exposed via jQuery's black box. Two possibilities: first try to precompile the Regex with `new RegExp ('_' + 'INDEX' + '_', flags)` (separating it out like that to avoid triggering any internal substitutions); or else try to rewrite the procedure in pure JavaScript without jQuery. I'd try the first option first.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or stack snipped that shows the problem?

Comment: What about `.split('__INDEX__').join(contactIndex)`?

Comment: @wp78de I haven't been able to replicate the error, it just comes through my error tracking software every once in a while. Code wise it's literally just the second snippet in the OP

Comment: @DenisRyabov & Jaifroid Thank you for the suggestions, I will try them both. I think split & join will be my best bet, but string based regex compilation should fix it too in theory. I won't be able to update this post anytime soon as the error only happens once every month or so, but thank you anyway